# Plotting Curvilinear Relationships from a Multi-Level Model in R

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, hierarchical-clustering, multi-level

I'm attempting to plot a curvilinear effect with including covariates from a multi-level model (HLM) in R (see model below)

`modelUF_US2 = lmer(ufeel ~ age_c + nat + extra_c + trait_sk_c + neuro_c + agree_c + open_c + g.usuccess + usuccess_cwc + usuccess_cwc2 + trait_sk_c2 (usuccess_cwc | subject),
                  data = S6_MLM,
                  REML = 0,
                  na.action = "na.omit",)`

Where usuccess_cwc2 is the squared term of usuccess_cwc that I'm looking to plot.

I've looked over posts discussing how to model curvilinear effects using [simple models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23334360/plot-polynomial-regression-curve-in-r) and [MLMs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9447329/how-to-plot-the-results-of-a-mixed-model) , but haven't figured out how to combine these two approaches.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [sjPlot-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjPlot) for that. Use `sjp.lmer(modelUF_US2, type = "effect")` to plot marginal effects for all fixed effects of your model.

If you just want to plot the marginal effect for the polynomial term, use:

```
sjp.lmer(modelUF_US2, type = "poly", poly.term = "usuccess_cwc")
```

However, you need to re-specify your model and square `usuccess_cwc` inside the formula before:

```
modelUF_US2 <- 
  lmer(ufeel ~ age_c + nat + extra_c + trait_sk_c +
         neuro_c + agree_c + open_c + g.usuccess + usuccess_cwc +
         I(usuccess_cwc) ^ 2 + trait_sk_c2 + (usuccess_cwc | subject),
       data = S6_MLM, REML = 0, na.action = na.omit)

library(sjPlot)
sjp.lmer(modelUF_US2, type = "poly", poly.term = "usuccess_cwc")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Strangely, when I re-specify the model incorporating I(usuccess_cwc)^2 - the fixed effect model matrix becomes rank deficient ("fixed-effect model matrix is rank deficient so dropping 1 column / coefficient").  I've read [this post](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/35071/what-is-rank-deficiency-and-how-to-deal-with-it) and it doesn't seem like my data should be fine. 

Have you used that function before in multilevel models?

Comment: See the help page `?sjp.lmer`, one of the last examples there uses a polynomial term in the formula.